# Expo 36: Unable to resolve "../../data" from "node_modules/css-tree/lib/syntax/default.js"

Tags: expo, react-native-svg

Got this error after upgrading expo 35 to 36.

```
Unable to resolve "../../data" from "node_modules/css-tree/lib/syntax/default.js"
```

I've tried to `yarn add css-tree`. This error was gone, but then module `react-native-svg` started giving the same error with it's included `css-tree` module.

I've tried to upgrad `expo-cli` to the latest version and restart terminal. I'm running builds with `expo start -c` to ensure cache doesn't affect it. I've tried to delete app from the simulator. Still the same.

I've been able to apply a temporary fix by upgrading `css-tree` dependency inside the `react-native-svg`, but this is a really wrong way to go as far as I know.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to fix it, you just need to install css-tree package on your project.

`npm install css-tree`

or if you are using yarn

`yarn add css-tree`

Answer (score 1):

as of SDK 38 this problem still shows up and seems to be caused by a version resolution issue where Yarn/NPM understands `1.0.0-alpha9` to be more recent then `1.0.0-alpha.37` (which is the minimum requirement for `react-native-svg-transformer`).

Using the `resolutions` override with Yarn 2 or Yarn 1 as follows fixed it for me with no other extra tweaking.

```
"resolutions": {
    "css-tree": "1.0.0-alpha.39"
}
```

```
"resolutions": {
    "**/css-tree": "1.0.0-alpha.39"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use `react-native-svg-icon` ran into the exact same issue.

I'm also running Expo SDK v36, and when it suggested me to install react-native-svg via the cli : `expo install react-native-svg`, that's what I did; there were errors with this approach most notably when you use `import { Circle } from 'react-native-svg'` (for newer versions of the package) and 'expo' sometimes doesn't install the package.json properly so I found installing the same version of react-native-svg w/o expo cli was the best approach.

Try running this `npm i react-native-svg@9.13.3`

Fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurred for me when building my app using MS App Center, the App Center build scripts picked up on an old yarn.lock file in the project using the line `if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then { yarn install && yarn list --depth=0; } else npm install; fi` however I normally use npm rather than Yarn.

Removing this file allowed the build to use npm which resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by installing:

```bash
npm install mdn-data
```